# Can't get data from mysql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, post, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to get some data from a mysql database.

The backend seems to work fine, the data is being logged there but not in the frontend.

```
app.post('/api/user/database_test', (req, res, next) => {

  var result;

  database.query('SELECT * FROM test', function (error, response, fields) {
    if (error) throw error; 
    console.log('response:', response);

     result = response; 
     console.log('result: ', result) //works fine
  })

  res.status(200).json({
    message: 'Data from Database :',
    result: result
  })
});
```

This is displayed in the backend console:

```
result:  [
  RowDataPacket {
    userid: '1',
    username: 'testuser',
    firstname: 'testname',
    lasname: 'testname2',
    email: 'test.test@test.de',
  }
]
```

But i also need to display the data i the frontend so i tried it like this.

```
 async getFromDB() {

    var obj = 'test';

    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/user/database_test', obj)
      .subscribe((response) => {
        
        console.log('response: ', response)  


      })
  }
```

But i only receive the message 'Data from database' in the browser console but no actual data. I also tried to log response.result but the code does not compile anymore.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Open the devtools and look into network tab to see the request. Maybe something is wrong. Paste the image if you can :)

Comment: Try taking the `async` off your method, returning the Observable in your service method, and subscribing to it in the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the backend code: `db.query` is async, so `res.json` returns results before db part is done, so you return empty results to the client, before they're actually pulled.

Try moving the response part inside `db.query`, so that `res.json` runs when the `db.query` is done:

```
app.post('/api/user/database_test', (req, res, next) => {


    database.query('SELECT * FROM test', function(error, response, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log('response:', response);

        console.log('result: ', response) //works fine

        res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Data from Database :',
            result: response
        });

    })


});
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you very much, i will upvote as soon as i have enough reputation :)